# how to create ssh connection with remote mongodb server using mongohub and a private key

Tags: ssh, mongodb

i'm using trying to use mongohub to access data on a remote mongodb server.  right now I can ssh on to the server using the following command:

```
ssh -i mykey.pem ubuntu@xx.xxx.x.xxx
```

The userid is ubuntu and I can point to the key file, but mongohub keeps crashing.  [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sE9WVXYC7DM) explains how to configure when using a password, but i'm just trying to use a key.  Also, I don't want to mess around with the ssh file on our db as it's up and running.  Hoping there's a quick set-up.

Comment: This is not a good way to ask for help. There are no error messages, no log file outputs, no list of things tried without success. Above all, there is no clear indication of why the two things (ssh and the crash in mongodb) should be connected.

Comment: Rather than print the entire crash report here, i'm hoping there's a nice little tutorial someone can point me toward on how to configure the server connection in mongohub.

Comment: I would suggest googling for "passwordless ssh" if the link you gave was not enough. Or otherwise follow what you were asked in the form or "I tried this, but but couldn't get it to work here, because of this"